# 3DNES file load problem?

Tags: macos, nes, wine

So I'm in the application 3DNES by geod, (if you haven't heard of it, check this out for information on the question or good old-fashioned fun. It's really cool- https://geod.itch.io/3dnes). I'm running this through a WineBottler-ified version of the Windows app because the Mac version costs five bucks and I don't have a PayPal. Point is, I can't seem to get roms to load. I'll navigate over to my downloads, and all that picking a rom will do is load a blank gray/black screen, then crash the app. Any kind of compilation/navigation-to-downloads/roms instructions accompanying an answer would be great for me, considering I'm not totally sure I'm doing it right. I'm a noob, I know. That's why I came here.

Edit: I'm fairly sure this is just a file-hunting problem, Windows on Mac tends to be finicky. Good luck!

Comment: What mac are you using? it is very likely that the software doesn't properly interface with the GPU when ran with wine. Another big problem is if it doesn't support the unix filesystem, as unix uses "/folder/folder" and windows uses "drive:\folder\folder".

Comment: @Judge2020 MacBook Air. You need a serial?

Comment: Jeez, this has gotten still NO attention aside from Judge's comment

Comment: Anything else about the scenario? If not, try converting the file maybe.

Comment: @YoshiLikes There's nothing peculiar in that area, Winebottler just opens the same thing in its own app, and the game files are already .nes.

Comment: Really, this needs more attention...

Comment: Maybe you can try redownloading the files. I really don't know what to tell you.

Comment: @YoshiLikes The files are fine, they work well on my Mac-based emulators.

Comment: There's no answer to reward a bounty to :(

Comment: Well i can't say anything else, i am out of possibilities.